# segment fault when implementing a linked list

Tags: c

i am trying to impliment a linked list but apprear a error, segmentation fault, I dont know why this is and how to fix this problem; here is my code:

```
    void delete_list(LIST L)
    {
        position p;

        p = L->next;
        L->next = NULL;
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            free(p);
            p = p->next; 
        }
    }
```

it should be somewhere in delete or empty but i dont know how to fix it, anyone can help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `delete_list`

```
  free(p);
  p = p->next;
```

you free memory, and then trying to access it. You need some `tmp` pointer that will hold `p->next` when you freeing `p`.

maybe something like that:

```
    position p,t;

    p = L->next;
    L->next = NULL;

    while( p )
    {
        t = p;
        p=p->next;
        free(t);
    }
```